# 値の指定について

Tags: python

CSVファイルを読み込んで計算をおこなっているのですが、棒グラフを作成するときのX座標をCSVで作成している表のヘッダー部分にしたいのですがうまく出力されません。

下記のコードを打ってるのですが `X=` の後は何をうてばいいのでしょうか？
先にHeaderの値を何かで指定するべきなのでしょうか？

```
plt.bar(x=header,height=model,)
```

Comment: 質問に記述されている情報が少なくて回答しようとする側で推測して埋めなければならないことが多岐にわたるため、助言や回答を得ることは難しいでしょう。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に、コピペして試せる程度にまとめたソースコードとサンプルデータをテキストで提示してみてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3765)

Comment: 「うまく出力されません」とはどういう状況でしょうか？（想定したいたグラフと異なるグラフが表示された、とかエラーが発生したなど具体的に教えてください。） また、コードは断片的ではなく全体を掲載されると回答者が回答しやすくなります。

Answer (score 1):

通常 CSVファイルをデータフレームに読み込むとヘッダは列名になるので，X座標に列名を設定して描画する記述例を示します。
test.csv:

```
,rat,ox,tiger,rabbit
Q1,1,2,3,4
Q2,5,6,7,8
Q3,9,10,11,12
```

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col=0)

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.bar(df.columns, df.loc['Q1'], label='Q1')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: 描画結果1]
また，X座標に数値を設定して全ての行を横並びに描画した後にX軸を列名にする記述例も示します。

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col=0)

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
x = np.arange(df.columns.size)
w = 0.8 / df.index.size
xt = x + (w / 2) * (df.index.size - 1)

for i, lb in enumerate(df.index):
    plt.bar(x + w * i, df.loc[lb], width=w, label=lb)

plt.xticks(xt, df.columns)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: 描画結果2]